# find multiple patterns in a string

Tags: python, pattern-matching

i know this might sound simple but i want a second opinion.

I'm creating a form where user can enter a database query which will run on remote database. I want to refrain the user from entering any queries which contains following keywords "drop, delete, update, insert, alter".

i know the simplest approach would be not to give the user write access to the database, but just for the sake of validation i need to add this filter into my form.

here's what i have done so far

```
Query = "Select * from table_name"

validation = re.search("DROP|drop|DELETE|delete|UPDATE|update|INSERT|insert|ALTER|alter",Query)

if validation:

    print "Oh! you are not supposed to enter that!!"

else:

    print "We're cool"
```

Have i covered every possible scenarios? or the user can still give me a hard time?

**Edited**

okay, so apparently this validation also restricts the keywords without the word boundry

`validation = re.search("drop|delete|update|insert|alter",Query,flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

I mean if my query is something like

Query = "Select * from droplets"

it won't pass through, similarly anything like "Select * from Inserted_Value_Table" will not pass either.

```
validation = re.search("\bdrop\b|\bdelete\b|\bupdate\b|\binsert\b|\balter\b",Query,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

now again i wonder if something like this would do the job?

Comment: if you use re.IGNORECASE  you don't have to add upper and lowercase strings in your pattern but there is nothing wrong with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use `any()`. But your approach seems to be sufficient:

```
t = Query.lower()
forbiddens = ('drop', 'delete', 'update', 'insert', 'alter')

if any(i in t for i in forbiddens):
    print "Oh! you are not supposed to enter that!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

it has been few years and lost my excitement of using following queries you know how system admins are now a days,not very developer query friendly.But you are my only friend for providing user such a great database interface :)

```
CREATE USER Hemraj WITH PASSWORD 'thanks_for_access';
TRUNCATE table_name;
CREATE TABLE project_financial_transaction (
 myprofit   text
 );
CREATE DATABASE superman OWNER Hemraj
```

As a user check for above queries too with following regex:

```
query = "Select * from table_name"
not_valid = re.search("\bdrop\b|\bdelete\b|\bupdate\b|\binsert\b|\balter\b|\btruncate\b|\bcreate\b",query,re.I)

if not_valid: 
    print "Invaid Query"
else:
    print result
```

If you are going to use this regex at many places in your code just compile it first like this:

```
not_valid = re.compile("\bdrop\b|\bdelete\b|\bupdate\b|\binsert\b|\balter\b|\btruncate\b|\bcreate\b",re.I)
if not_valid.search(query):
    print "Invalid Query"
```

this way you can keep your code clean and more readable :)